# Pandas sort on index throws "unhashable type: 'list'" error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I create my dataset as follows (intentionally out of order):

```
pa = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('1', '2'),('2', '1'),('1', '4'),('1', '5'),('1', '3'),('2', '2'),('2', '3'),('3', '1'),('3', '2'),('1', '1')]
                           , names=['batch', 'run'])
yld=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1),index=pa,columns=['yield'])
```

when I try to a sort on the `batch` & `run` index columns:

```
yld.sort_index(['batch','run'])
```

I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

I don't have a clue what is going wrong..

Comment: `yld.sort_index(level=['batch','run'])` level sort should mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sort_index has positional starting with `axis` then `level`, then you must use `level=`, see sort_index signature below:

Signature: yld.sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', sort_remaining=True, by=None)

Therefore the correct syntax is as @Wen suggest.

```
yld.sort_index(level=['batch','run'])
```

or

```
yld.sort_index()
```

because the level would automatically would sort on index levels outside in.